# two timers calling each other

Tags: java, timer

I have two timers from the java.util.Timer class. The timer hits a condition and starts the other timer and before it starts the other timer it stops the original timer. This goes back and further like the following:

```
private void StartGame() 
{
    RankTimer.cancel();
    InGame = true;
    timeLeft = GamePeriod;
    InGameTimer.purge();
    InGameTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            timeLeft = timeLeft-timerUpdate;
            if(timeLeft<=0)
            {
                StartRank();
            }
        }
    }, 0, timerUpdate);

}
protected void StartRank() 
{

    InGameTimer.cancel();
    GameDataChange();
    InGame = false;
    timeLeft = RankPeriod;
    RankTimer.purge();
    RankTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            timeLeft = timeLeft-timerUpdate;
            if(timeLeft<=0)
            {
                StartGame();
            }
        }
    }, 0, timerUpdate);
}
```

The timers are RankTimer and InGameTimer. While the code was running at a certain point I got the following error:

Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Unknown Source)
    at demo.ServerGameThread.StartRank(ServerGameThread.java:76)
    at demo.ServerGameThread$1.run(ServerGameThread.java:64)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

I did a purge too before setting the scheduler. The idea is that these timers will run infinitely calling one another stopping each other while starting up their own task. Any ideas why it's failing? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I can do what I want with only one timer as such:

```
    private void StartGame() 
{
    InGame = true;
    InGrace = false;
    timeLeft = GamePeriod + GracePeriod + RankPeriod;

    GameTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            timeLeft = timeLeft-timerUpdate;
            if(timeLeft<=GracePeriod + RankPeriod && timeLeft>RankPeriod)
            {
                InGrace = true;
            }
            else if(timeLeft<=RankPeriod && timeLeft>0)
            {
                GameDataChange();
                InGame = false;
                InGrace = false;
            }
            else if(timeLeft<=0)
            {
                InGame = true;
                timeLeft = GamePeriod + GracePeriod + RankPeriod;
            }
        }
    }, 0, timerUpdate);
```

I added the GracePeriod part which isn't that much different from the previous code. I just reset the timeLeft variable to it's initial starting value to start the cycle again.